# When does a ComboBox receive its Items if it is bound to ObservableCollection?

Tags: wpf, combobox, selecteditem, lazy-initialization

I am attempting a save/load mechanism for re-use in a business application.  I have the groundwork laid to read/write `ObservableCollection<>` to/from `xml`, using attributes to describe my class properties.  That part is working.  I can save an `ObservableCollection` to `XML`, then load the `XML` back into an `ObservableCollection` the next time I run the program.

Here's my problem.  I have a `ComboBox` whose `ItemsSource.DataContext = ObservableCollection<Flag>;`
When I run the program, it accepts the binding just fine, but the `ComboBox` itself does not populate itself until later.  I want to set the SelectedItem to be the first item in the `ObservableCollection<Flag>` that I have loaded from XML.  Nothing happens though, because as the program is executing it's startup methods, the `Items.Count` remains `0`.  I'm guessing the `ComboBox` doesn't populate itself until it gets focus.  How do I work around this?  Can I force the ComboBox to populate itself?  I've tried `cb_ARDAR_ARFlag.Items.Refresh();`

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="cb_ARDAR_ARFlag"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          SelectionChanged="cb_ARDAR_ARFlag_SelectionChanged">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Flag_Desc}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Relevant Code:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        setDataBinding();

        loadSavedData();
    }

    private void setDataBinding()
    {
        //Returns ObservableCollection<Flag>
        cb_ARDAR_ARFlag.DataContext = Flag.getOCAvailableFlags(); 
    }
    private void loadSavedData()
    {
        //When it gets here the ItemCount is 0 so nothing happens.
        //Refresh didn't help
        cb_ARDAR_ARFlag.Items.Refresh();
        Flag f = Enforcement_Save.loadOCARFlag().First();
        cb_ARDAR_ARFlag.SelectedItem = f;
    }
```

At this point I'm still not sure the code at the end will successfully identify the correct 'flag' item to be selected, or if I'll end up using Linq.  Which, by the way, leads me to another question.  Can you `Linq` to `ComboBox.Items` somehow?

Comment: All of this kind of stuff becomes a non issue if you use Bindings and a viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated your issue, and your are correct, the items count is = 0 in the loadSavedData method. The combobox doesn't seem to be populated until after the constructor has fully executed.

In the meantime I found you can use the ItemsSource property to load the combobox at the time you want it loaded:

`cb_ARDAR_ARFlag.ItemsSource = Flag.getOCAvailableFlags();`

Comment: That works just fine for my purpose.  Binding via DataContext won't be necessary for this purpose.